# Select updates other selects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have n number of selects generate with ng-repeat and I need to update the all the options in the other selects, when I change one of the select. I need to create a vote mechanism. Example:

```
Init:
- select 1: 1,2,3,4
- select 2: 1,2,3,4
- select 3: 1,2,3,4
- select 4: 1,2,3,4

After change select 1:
- select 1: 2 (selected)
- select 2: 1,3,4
- select 3: 1,3,4
- select 4: 1,3,4

After change select 2:
- select 1: 2 (selected)
- select 2: 4
- select 3: 1,3
- select 4: 1,3
...etc
```

The number of the selects is dynamic, options always show the number of the generated selects

My code so far:

```
<div ng-model="items">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <select ng-model="selectedPollNum" ng-change="changedPoll(selectedPollNum)">
            <option ng-repeat="option in items">{{ $index + 1 }}</option>
        </select>
        <label>{{item.name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gvwpgtj6/2/

Also options start with empty, and I want to start with the first one

Comment: This seems more like a (rather broad) to do / task, it's unclear to me what the *question* is? Can you share what you have so far, be explicit about the problem with your current solution?

Comment: Yes, sorry. So what I have at the moment is in jsFiddle (generated selects and options). What I want to achieve: for instance when I select a number from the first select, I want to remove the selected one from all the other selects...so I can't select the same number twice. Is that clear?

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve it rather than these `html`?

Comment: The empty option is generated when a value referenced by ng-model doesn't exist in a set of options passed to ng-options. This happens to prevent accidental model selection: AngularJS can see that the initial model is either undefined or not in the set of options and don't want to decide model value on its own.

If you want to get rid of the empty option just select an initial value in your controller. I also did find an example of what you're trying to achieve, but it's in JQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/dq97z/3/

Comment: Thanks @Matheno, that was one problem, I believe the smaller one. Can you give advice about the selection dependencies?

Comment: If, for example, you would initiate $scope.selectedPollNum = 1; in your controller, it would pre select the first option.

Comment: It was mostly clear from the post and jsfiddle what you intend. However, it's just a task you have to complete, not a programming question. The code in the OP nor the fiddle contain any attempt at completing that to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be your requirement. If you select an option by default in `select`, it is hard to hide the default selected options in other drop downs. So leaving empty is recommended.

**CONTROLLER:**

```js
function LoginController($scope) {
  $scope.arr = [];
  $scope.obj={};
  $scope.items = [{
    name: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
  }, {
    name: 'Consectetur adipiscing elit'
  }, {
    name: 'Fusce faucibus turpis eget'
  }, {
    name: 'Sed quis nisl sed ligula'
  }, {
    name: 'Nunc ultricies ipsum vitae'
  }];

  $scope.changedPoll = function(num, i) {
  $scope.obj[i] = num;$scope.arr=[]
    angular.forEach($scope.obj, function(value,key){
    $scope.arr.push(parseInt($scope.obj[key]))
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
  <div ng-model="items">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <select ng-model="selectedPollNum" ng-change="changedPoll(selectedPollNum, $index)">
        <option ng-repeat="option in items" ng-show='arr.indexOf($index + 1)<0'>{{ $index + 1}}</option>
      </select>
      <label>{{item.name}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is good! Nice! Can you change to number instead of name? In this case 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Also if I want to change one of the option after I selected I can't do, because it's already disappeared.